# Исключить часть плагинов из сборки

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

В настройках плагинов можно выставить, для какой платформы они используются: Standalone, iOS, Android и т.п.

Но как можно исключить какие-то плагины в рамках одной таргет платформы? К примеру, когда я собираю Steam версию игры, то мне не нужен Facebook плагин. Это плагин нужен только если я собираю Standalone для Gameroom магазина.

В случае с Android, к примеру, мне для Samsung Store нужны плагины, которые нет необходимость включать в Google Play билд.

Как такое возможно организовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент нашёл только [это](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/allow-tagging-folders-for-exclusion-in-builds) предложение 2016 года, которое так и не было реализовано.

Обратиться к настройкам плагина из кода нельзя. Так что, на сколько могу судить, пока что какого-то унифицированного решения нет.

Судя по [докам](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html), можно, к примеру, добавлять `~` в конце или менять расширение файла на `.tmp`, тогда такие файлы не войдут в билд:

> During the import process, Unity completely ignores the following
>   files and folders in the Assets folder (or a sub-folder within it):
>
> - Hidden folders.
> - Files and folders which start with ‘.’.
> - Files and folders which end with ‘~’.
> - Files and folders named cvs.
> - Files with the extension .tmp.

То есть, к примеру, можно что-то такое сделать:

1. Создать список свой, где для необходимых плагинов задать список платформ/магазинов, в которые этот билд должен войти.
2. На основе [BuildPlayerPipeline](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html), сделать скрипт, который перед билдом будет менять расширение на `.tmp`, а после окончания билда возвращать оригинальное.